# MacBook Pro integrated GPU drawing too much power when CPU monitoring app is running

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, gpu, cpu, temperature

**Main problem:**

[image]

When I run an app that monitors CPU temperature, it rises from 40° to 76° in 3 minutes. Even though the CPU usage is 12%, CPU package power draw maxes out at 31W. I checked the clock speeds and temperatures from iStat Menus. The CPU core power draw was only 7W at maximum and integrated GPU power draw was at 21W.

***My Question: How do I fix this?***

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Additional information:**

But GPU frequency was at 0MHz. When I use apps like Macs Fan Control that only displays temperatures as numbers not graphs, temperatures don't rise. Also, when using Intel Power Gadget, temperatures keep rising up to 92°. And when I close the lid of my Mac, it overheats, exceeding the CPU temperature limit and crashes. But when using iStat Menus, temperatures hover around 70°.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Driver issue. I was using an older version.